# How can make screen sessions to use same settings as original terminal

Tags: linux

When I run 'screen' command after logging into the linux terminal from putty,
I see font color of folders got changed.
earlier folders are shown with different color(blue)'
Now all files are in same color.
How can I make sure even screen sessions also use same font settings as original terminal?

Answer (score 0):

There really isn't enough information to answer this question, but here's a couple things you could do to troubleshoot.

Make sure that the `$SHELL` in screen is the same as the `$SHELL` in the original terminal (Run `echo $SHELL` before and after starting screen and compare the results). Perhaps screen is running a different shell and thus not reading your preferred .*rc file.

Also, try starting screen with a specific `TERM` value. Set screen's term value to `$TERM` before when starting screen like so:

```
screen -T $TERM
```

I would also recommend trying to replace `$TERM` with `xterm` if `$TERM` doesn't solve it.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried with screen -T $TERM , and $TERM is xterm only but it doesn't solve the issue. In addition to that I created .screenrc in home directory and exported LSCOLORS as export LS_COLORS=$LS_COLORS:'di=0;34:'; But still its not working.